# Resize images to fit image control in asp.net javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, web-applications

I change an image in the header based on which menu item is selected. The problem is that the image stretches in the image control. I want it to automatically zoom without distorting the image. Is this possible.

Note: The images reside in an images folder and are not all the same size.

Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function ChangeProjectImage(imgpath) {
        var img1 = document.getElementById("Image2")
        img1.src = imgpath;
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend setting the CSS property 'width'.  Use a width that suits your needs and your images.  It will be implemented like this:

```
width:300px;
```

Since you don't want to distort your images, you should likely use the smallest width that your images have.  All [these](http://jsfiddle.net/QegqM/) images have different widths, but since the 'width' property is set to `80px`, they all look like the same width, without distortion.

Comment: Your solution worked out great! Thank you. I made sure not to set the height property because that was distorting it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can automatically zoom, except you know how much zoom are you looking for.

**CSS**

```
Zoom:200%;
```

Comment: so i would have to mathamatically figure out the image size then set the Zoom style accordingly?